# Compute Prefix Function in String Matching

Tags: java, string, prefix

What am i doing wrong here?

Java code for computing prefix function. Two input are right but the last one is wrong.

Here's the pseudocode:

[image: Pseudocode]

Java code:

```
class Main {
// compute prefix function
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String p = "422213422153342";
        String x = "ababbabbabbababbabb";
        String y = "ababaca";

        printOutput(p);

        printOutput(y);

        System.out.println();System.out.println();
        System.out.println("the prefix func below is wrong. I am not sure why.");
        System.out.print("answer should be: 0 0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8");

        printOutput(x);
    }

    static void printOutput(String P){
        System.out.println();System.out.println();
        System.out.print("p[i]: ");
        for(int i = 0; i < P.length(); i++)System.out.print(P.charAt(i) + " ");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Pi[i]: ");
        compute_prefix_func(P);
    }
    public static void compute_prefix_func(String P){
        int m = P.length();
        int pi[] = new int[m];

        for(int i = 0; i < pi.length; i++){
            pi[i] = 0;
        }

        pi[0] = 0;

        int k = 0;

        for(int q = 2; q < m; q++){
            while(k > 0 && ( ((P.charAt(k) + "").equals(P.charAt(q) + "")) == false)){
                k = pi[k];
            }
            if ((P.charAt(k) + "").equals(P.charAt(q) + "")){
                k = k + 1;
            }
            pi[q] = k;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < pi.length; i++){
        System.out.print(pi[i] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In future, please include code directly in the post, rather than linking to another site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, let's start off by making the code *much* easier to read. This:

```
if ((P.charAt(k) + "").equals(P.charAt(q) + ""))
```

can be simplified to:

```
if (P.charAt(k) == P.charAt(q))
```

... and you've done that in multiple places.

Likewise here:

```
int pi[] = new int[m];

for(int i = 0; i < pi.length; i++){
    pi[i] = 0;
}

pi[0] = 0;
```

... you don't need the explicit initialization. Variables are 0-initialized by default. (It's unclear why you're then setting `pi[0]` *again*, although I note that if `P.length()` is 0, this will throw an exception.)

Next is to remove the explicit comparison with `false`, instead just using `!` so we have:

```
while(k > 0 && P.charAt(k) != P.charAt(q))
```

Finally, let's restructure the code a bit to make it easier to follow, use more conventional names, and change `int pi[]` to the more idiomatic `int[] pi`:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String x = "ababbabbabbababbabb";

        int[] prefix = computePrefix(x);

        System.out.println("Prefix series for " + x);
        for (int p : prefix) {
            System.out.print(p + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static int[] computePrefix(String input) {
        int[] pi = new int[input.length()];

        int k = 0;
        for(int q = 2; q < input.length(); q++) {            
            while (k > 0 && input.charAt(k) != input.charAt(q)) {
                k = pi[k];
            }
            if (input.charAt(k) == input.charAt(q)) {
                k = k + 1;
            }
            pi[q] = k;
        }
        return pi;
    }
}
```

That's now much easier to follow, IMO.

We can now look back to the pseudocode and see that it appears to be using 1-based indexing for both arrays and strings. That makes life slightly tricky. We *could* mimic that throughout the code, changing *every* array access and `charAt` call to just subtract 1.

(I've extracted the common subexpression of `P[q]` to a variable `target` within the loop.)

```
public static int[] computePrefix(String input) {
    int[] pi = new int[input.length()];
    int k = 0;
    for (int q = 2; q <= input.length(); q++) {
        char target = input.charAt(q - 1);
        while (k > 0 && input.charAt(k + 1 - 1) != target) {
            k = pi[k - 1];
        }
        if (input.charAt(k + 1 - 1) == target) {
            k++;
        }
        pi[q - 1] = k;
    }
    return pi;
}
```

That now gives your desired results, but it's really ugly. We can shift `q` very easily, and remove the `+ 1 - 1` parts:

```
public static int[] computePrefix(String input) {
    int[] pi = new int[input.length()];
    int k = 0;
    for (int q = 1; q < input.length(); q++) {
        char target = input.charAt(q);
        while (k > 0 && input.charAt(k) != target) {
            k = pi[k - 1];
        }
        if (input.charAt(k) == target) {
            k++;
        }
        pi[q] = k;
    }
    return pi;
}
```

It's still not entirely pleasant, but I think it's what you want. Make sure you understand *why* I had to make the changes I did.

Comment: how did you come from `input.charAt(k)` to `input.charAt(k + 1 - 1)`? especially the +1? seeing at the pseudocode it should be `input.charAt(k + 1)` no?

Comment: @Firo: The `+ 1` is in the pseudocode. The `- 1` comes from the fact that the pseudocode assumes 1-based arrays and character indexes, whereas Java uses 0-based values.

Comment: i meant that the "restructured" code misses the +1 in ´input.charAt(k)´ ;)

Comment: @Firo: Yes, that was refactoring but not *fixing* the original code.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int[] computePrefix(String input) {
    int[] pi = new int[input.length()];
    pi[0] = -1;
    int k = -1;
    for (int q = 1; q < input.length(); q++) {
        char target = input.charAt(q);
        while (k > 0 && input.charAt(k + 1) != target) {
            k = pi[k];
        }
        if (input.charAt(k + 1) == target) {
            k++;
        }
        pi[q] = k;
    }
    return pi;
}
```